# running word count in OpenOffice writer

Tags: openoffice, word-count

In OpenOffice Writer 3.4.1 is there a way to show the word count as you type without clicking anything? I'm new with OpenOffice and am use to word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Live Word Count python marco](https://bitbucket.org/yawaramin/oo.o-live-word-count/raw/tip/wc.py)

- Install python
- Create Macro
- Add Macro to your menu bar in OO
- Create shortcut for the Live Word Count macro

[image: Live Word Count Macro Screenshot]

More details can be found: 
http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Blogs/Productivity-Sauce/Add-Instant-Word-Count-Feature-to-OpenOffice.org-Writer